# Counting the number of matches between two ranges

Tags: excel

I am seeking a formula to count the number of matching numbers between two range of cells. I want to explain with examples. It can be confusing.

`A1:E1={1,2,3,4,5}` and `A2:E2={2,1,3,5,4}`: here two groups have the same numbers, so there are 5 matches. (Order is not important)

`A1:E1={1,1,1,1,1}` and `A2:E2={1,2,1,1,1}`: here two groups have four 1s, so it is 4 matches.

`A1:E1={2,2,1,1,1}` and `A2:E2={2,2,2,1,1}`: here two groups have two 2s, and two 1s matching, so it is 4 matches in total.

`A1:E1= {1,4,4,3,7}` and `A2:E2={4,3,5,6,1}`, in this case both groups have one 4, one 1, one 3. So it is 3 matches in total.

Please let me know if anything is unclear. The challenging part here is repetitions.

Comment: yes, as an example. but it won't be very large data either.

Comment: the sets will be of equal length. if one group has 5 digits, the other will have 5 digits too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I just know someone will do this far more concisely but this does work

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(A1:E1,N(OFFSET(A1,ROW(A1:E2)-ROW(A1),COLUMN(A1:E2)-COLUMN(A1),1,1)))<
FREQUENCY(A2:E2,N(OFFSET(A1,ROW(A1:E2)-ROW(A1),COLUMN(A1:E2)-COLUMN(A1),1,1))),
FREQUENCY(A1:E1,N(OFFSET(A1,ROW(A1:E2)-ROW(A1),COLUMN(A1:E2)-COLUMN(A1),1,1))),
FREQUENCY(A2:E2,N(OFFSET(A1,ROW(A1:E2)-ROW(A1),COLUMN(A1:E2)-COLUMN(A1),1,1)))))
```

The idea being that you combine the two lists using offset, then compare the frequencies. The lower frequency is the one that will be taken.

[image]

Have added an extra case - the first four give the correct answer if you just sort the two lists and compare them but the last one doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

try the two attempts below:

```
{=SUM(COUNTIF(A1:A5,B1:B5))}
```

Or

```
{=SUM(IF(COUNTIF(A1:A5,B1:B5)=1,1,0))+SUM(IF(COUNTIF(A1:A5,B1:B5)>1,1,0))}
```

Both need entering as an array using **Ctrl + Shift + Enter**

Comment: I tried the first formula before it doesn't give the correct result. And second formula is the same unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done, but it requires few steps. It will only work if matching values are from 0-9.
first, enter this formula `=CONCATENATE(A2,B2,C2,D2,E2)` in cell `I2` and drag it to the bottom. 
[image]

then enter this formula `=SUBSTITUTE(I2,A1,"",1)` in cell J2 and drag it to column `N` and to the bottom.

[image]

Lastly, enter this formula `=5-LEN(N2)` in cell `G2` and copy/paste it beside searching values.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Not sure if this will solve your problem, but this **array formula** (click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> together) will get the same results as you are stating here:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(SMALL($A2:$E2,COLUMN($A2:$E2))=SMALL($A1:$E1,COLUMN($A1:$E1))))
```

What I did is to rank both rows and count how many are matching.  But let me know if this will cover all the scenarios you have or not.